# Extract the role from an Oauth bearer token

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt

I want to extract the role from an OAuth bearer token of the form

```
Authorization: Bearer xyz123
```

What is the best way to do this in Java ?

Comment: What role do you mean? Like the role used for authorization? If so, does the token even contain any such information, i.e. is it a JWT? If not then you'd need to look that up somewhere else but where and how would depend on where the roles per user are stored etc.- Even if the token was a JWT it might still not contain any role information. In that case a lookup would be needed as well.

Comment: If by "role" you mean the user's role (e.g. admin, guest...) then this kind of information must be stored in a database and linked to the user. The token itself should be a very short lived string that you compare with a set of valid tokens from your database and then read the user information that is related to that token.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. So if I understand correctly, I need to look up the roles using the user information contained in the token. So what is the best way of obtaining the user information from the token ? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to understand but the role should be managed as part of claims handling and not stored in the token itself - and a database lookup can be used - as recommended above. Here are some notes on concepts I usually recommend: https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/